# Why do I get an SyntaxErrorException while executing query on DB2?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, db2

I tried to get the countries beginning with L, however I get an error when I try to use the `WHERE COUNTRY INTO 'L%'` statement.

```
String sql = "SELECT COUNTRY, LER "  
 + "FROM CENSUS.WORLDIMR "    
 + "WHERE COUNTRY INTO 'L%'";
```

I recieve the following exception:

```
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-199, SQLSTAT
E=42601, SQLERRMC=INTO;??( [ CONCAT || / MICROSECONDS MICROSECOND SECONDS SECOND
, DRIVER=4.18.74
```

It's definitely something wrong with `WHERE COUNTRY INTO 'L%'`. I had the same problem with COBOL. Adding 29 times % fixed it but this time it's different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need to use LIKE operator:

```
SELECT COUNTRY, LER FROM CENSUS.WORLDIMR WHERE COUNTRY LIKE 'L%';
```